# pyqt5 : Unable to maximize widgets on Window resize

Tags: pyqt5, frame, autoresize

I want to show a few data on the screen (These are inputs and outputs from RPi).
I also want to show a chart. (I got sample code here https://codeloop.org/pyqtchart-how-to-create-barchart-in-pyqt5/)
I am having one issue though. I am not able to get the widgets resize when the screen resizes. Even when maximized the size remains the same.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'prodwindowui3.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QBarSet, QPercentBarSeries, QBarCategoryAxis
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(923, 480)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 751, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.lytHTitle = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.lytHTitle.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lytHTitle.setObjectName("lytHTitle")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.lytHTitle.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.lblTitle = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.lblTitle.setObjectName("lblTitle")
        self.lytHTitle.addWidget(self.lblTitle)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.lytHTitle.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 791, 241))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.lytH_Top = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.lytH_Top.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.lytH_Top.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lytH_Top.setSpacing(10)
        self.lytH_Top.setObjectName("lytH_Top")
        self.frmInput = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(12)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmInput.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmInput.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmInput.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmInput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmInput.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmInput.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmInput.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmInput.setObjectName("frmInput")
        self.layoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput)
        self.layoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 35, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_5.setObjectName("layoutWidget_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.setObjectName("lytV_Input_label_3")
        self.lblInput0_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput0_3.setObjectName("lblInput0_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput0_3)
        self.lblInput1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput1_3.setObjectName("lblInput1_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput1_3)
        self.lblInput2_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput2_3.setObjectName("lblInput2_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput2_3)
        self.lblInput3_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput3_3.setObjectName("lblInput3_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput3_3)
        self.layoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput)
        self.layoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 46, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_6.setObjectName("layoutWidget_6")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.setObjectName("lytV_Input_Status_3")
        self.lblInput0_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput0_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput0_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput0_Status_3)
        self.lblInput1_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput1_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput1_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput1_Status_3)
        self.lblInput2_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput2_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput2_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput2_Status_3)
        self.lblInput3_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput3_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput3_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput3_Status_3)
        self.lblOStatus_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmInput)
        self.lblOStatus_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_2.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_2.setObjectName("lblOStatus_2")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmInput)
        self.frmOutput = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmOutput.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmOutput.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmOutput.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmOutput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmOutput.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmOutput.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmOutput.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmOutput.setObjectName("frmOutput")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_22 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmOutput)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 41, 178))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_22.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_22")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.setObjectName("lytV_Output_Status_3")
        self.lblOutput0_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput0_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput0_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput0_Status_3)
        self.lblOutput1_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput1_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput1_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput1_Status_3)
        self.lblOutput2_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput2_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput2_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput2_Status_3)
        self.lblOutput3_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput3_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput3_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput3_Status_3)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_23 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmOutput)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 41, 178))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_23.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_23")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.setObjectName("lytV_Output_Label_3")
        self.lblOutput0_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput0_3.setObjectName("lblOutput0_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput0_3)
        self.lblOutput1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput1_3.setObjectName("lblOutput1_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput1_3)
        self.lblOutput2_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput2_3.setObjectName("lblOutput2_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput2_3)
        self.lblOutput3_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput3_3.setObjectName("lblOutput3_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput3_3)
        self.lblOStatus_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmOutput)
        self.lblOStatus_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_3.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_3.setObjectName("lblOStatus_3")
        self.lblOStatus_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmOutput)
        self.lblOStatus_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 41, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_4.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_4.setObjectName("lblOStatus_4")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmOutput)
        self.frmInput_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(12)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmInput_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmInput_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmInput_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmInput_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmInput_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmInput_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmInput_2.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmInput_2.setObjectName("frmInput_2")
        self.layoutWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_2)
        self.layoutWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 35, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_7.setObjectName("layoutWidget_7")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.setObjectName("lytV_Input_label_4")
        self.lblInput0_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput0_4.setObjectName("lblInput0_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput0_4)
        self.lblInput1_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput1_4.setObjectName("lblInput1_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput1_4)
        self.lblInput2_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput2_4.setObjectName("lblInput2_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput2_4)
        self.lblInput3_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput3_4.setObjectName("lblInput3_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput3_4)
        self.layoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_2)
        self.layoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 46, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_8.setObjectName("layoutWidget_8")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.setObjectName("lytV_Input_Status_4")
        self.lblInput0_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput0_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput0_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput0_Status_4)
        self.lblInput1_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput1_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput1_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput1_Status_4)
        self.lblInput2_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput2_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput2_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput2_Status_4)
        self.lblInput3_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput3_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput3_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput3_Status_4)
        self.lblOStatus_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmInput_2)
        self.lblOStatus_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_5.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_5.setObjectName("lblOStatus_5")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmInput_2)
        self.frmInput_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(12)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmInput_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmInput_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmInput_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmInput_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmInput_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmInput_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmInput_3.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmInput_3.setObjectName("frmInput_3")
        self.layoutWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_3)
        self.layoutWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 35, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_9.setObjectName("layoutWidget_9")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.setObjectName("lytV_Input_label_5")
        self.lblInput0_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput0_5.setObjectName("lblInput0_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput0_5)
        self.lblInput1_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput1_5.setObjectName("lblInput1_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput1_5)
        self.lblInput2_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput2_5.setObjectName("lblInput2_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput2_5)
        self.lblInput3_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput3_5.setObjectName("lblInput3_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput3_5)
        self.layoutWidget_10 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_3)
        self.layoutWidget_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 46, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_10.setObjectName("layoutWidget_10")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.setObjectName("lytV_Input_Status_5")
        self.lblInput0_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput0_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput0_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput0_Status_5)
        self.lblInput1_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput1_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput1_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput1_Status_5)
        self.lblInput2_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput2_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput2_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput2_Status_5)
        self.lblInput3_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput3_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput3_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput3_Status_5)
        self.lblOStatus_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmInput_3)
        self.lblOStatus_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_6.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_6.setObjectName("lblOStatus_6")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmInput_3)
        self.lytH_Top.setStretch(0, 10)
        self.lytH_Top.setStretch(1, 10)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 791, 210))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_3")
        self.lytH_Chart = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.lytH_Chart.setContentsMargins(1, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lytH_Chart.setSpacing(3)
        self.lytH_Chart.setObjectName("lytH_Chart")
        self.widget_Chart = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget_Chart.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget_Chart.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget_Chart.setObjectName("widget_Chart")
        self.lytH_Chart.addWidget(self.widget_Chart)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 923, 18))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lblTitle.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                         "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">TEST DATA SHOW</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.lblInput0_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input0"))
        self.lblInput1_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input1"))
        self.lblInput2_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input2"))
        self.lblInput3_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input3"))
        self.lblInput0_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput1_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput2_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput3_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOStatus_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INPUT"))
        self.lblOutput0_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOutput1_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOutput2_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOutput3_Status_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOutput0_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output0"))
        self.lblOutput1_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output1"))
        self.lblOutput2_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output2"))
        self.lblOutput3_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output3"))
        self.lblOStatus_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INPUT"))
        self.lblOStatus_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>OUTPUT</p></body></html>"))
        self.lblInput0_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input0"))
        self.lblInput1_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input1"))
        self.lblInput2_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input2"))
        self.lblInput3_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input3"))
        self.lblInput0_Status_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput1_Status_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput2_Status_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput3_Status_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOStatus_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INPUT"))
        self.lblInput0_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input0"))
        self.lblInput1_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input1"))
        self.lblInput2_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input2"))
        self.lblInput3_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input3"))
        self.lblInput0_Status_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput1_Status_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput2_Status_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblInput3_Status_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lblOStatus_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INPUT"))

    def create_bar(self):
        # The QBarSet class represents a set of bars in the bar chart.
        # It groups several bars into a bar set

        set0 = QBarSet("Parwiz")
        set1 = QBarSet("Bob")
        set2 = QBarSet("Tom")
        set3 = QBarSet("Logan")
        set4 = QBarSet("Karim")

        set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6
        set1 << 5 << 0 << 0 << 4 << 0 << 7
        set2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 13 << 8 << 5
        set3 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 3 << 4 << 5
        set4 << 9 << 7 << 5 << 3 << 1 << 2

        series = QPercentBarSeries()
        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.append(set3)
        series.append(set4)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Percent Example")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        categories = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
        axis = QBarCategoryAxis()
        axis.append(categories)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAxisX(axis, series)

        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.lytH_Chart.addWidget(chartView)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.create_bar()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am using QFrame to show a box around each set of Data. I tried to set the Horizontal and Vertical Policy under size policy as expanding also.
Nothing happens. I even used horizontal spacers.
Can some please guide. Thanks

Comment: You're only setting layouts for the "layout widgets" you're creating, but those widget are not managed by a parent layout, which is what should be set on the central widget. Right click on an empty area outside any other widget, and select the appropriate layout from the "Lay out" submenu.

Comment: I am very sorry. I missed your answer. Yes, you are right. I accidently came across the solution. When I was trying to save a dialog design in QT Designer it showed an error "t designer this file contains top level spacers" which led me to the solution that everything should be enclosed in a parent layout . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am still learning the QT Designer. <s>I could find out the problem</s>.
In fact the 3 Horizontal layouts should go into a main layout (I used a vertical layout).
This solved my problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'prodialog.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QBarSet, QPercentBarSeries, QBarCategoryAxis
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(941, 545)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lytHTitle = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lytHTitle.setObjectName("lytHTitle")
        self.lblTitle = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.lblTitle.setObjectName("lblTitle")
        self.lytHTitle.addWidget(self.lblTitle)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.lytHTitle)
        self.lytH_Top = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lytH_Top.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.lytH_Top.setSpacing(10)
        self.lytH_Top.setObjectName("lytH_Top")
        self.frmInput = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmInput.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmInput.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmInput.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmInput.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 208))
        self.frmInput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmInput.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmInput.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmInput.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmInput.setObjectName("frmInput")
        self.layoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput)
        self.layoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 35, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_5.setObjectName("layoutWidget_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.setObjectName("lytV_Input_label_3")
        self.lblInput0_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput0_3.setObjectName("lblInput0_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput0_3)
        self.lblInput1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput1_3.setObjectName("lblInput1_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput1_3)
        self.lblInput2_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput2_3.setObjectName("lblInput2_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput2_3)
        self.lblInput3_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_5)
        self.lblInput3_3.setObjectName("lblInput3_3")
        self.lytV_Input_label_3.addWidget(self.lblInput3_3)
        self.layoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput)
        self.layoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 46, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_6.setObjectName("layoutWidget_6")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.setObjectName("lytV_Input_Status_3")
        self.lblInput0_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput0_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput0_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput0_Status_3)
        self.lblInput1_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput1_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput1_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput1_Status_3)
        self.lblInput2_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput2_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput2_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput2_Status_3)
        self.lblInput3_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.lblInput3_Status_3.setObjectName("lblInput3_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblInput3_Status_3)
        self.lblOStatus_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmInput)
        self.lblOStatus_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_2.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_2.setObjectName("lblOStatus_2")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmInput)
        self.frmOutput = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmOutput.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmOutput.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmOutput.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmOutput.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 208))
        self.frmOutput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmOutput.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmOutput.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmOutput.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmOutput.setObjectName("frmOutput")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_22 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmOutput)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 41, 178))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_22.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_22")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.setObjectName("lytV_Output_Status_3")
        self.lblOutput0_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput0_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput0_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput0_Status_3)
        self.lblOutput1_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput1_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput1_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput1_Status_3)
        self.lblOutput2_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput2_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput2_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput2_Status_3)
        self.lblOutput3_Status_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_22)
        self.lblOutput3_Status_3.setObjectName("lblOutput3_Status_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Status_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput3_Status_3)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_23 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmOutput)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 41, 178))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_23.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_23")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.setObjectName("lytV_Output_Label_3")
        self.lblOutput0_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput0_3.setObjectName("lblOutput0_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput0_3)
        self.lblOutput1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput1_3.setObjectName("lblOutput1_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput1_3)
        self.lblOutput2_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput2_3.setObjectName("lblOutput2_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput2_3)
        self.lblOutput3_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_23)
        self.lblOutput3_3.setObjectName("lblOutput3_3")
        self.lytV_Output_Label_3.addWidget(self.lblOutput3_3)
        self.lblOStatus_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmOutput)
        self.lblOStatus_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_3.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_3.setObjectName("lblOStatus_3")
        self.lblOStatus_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmOutput)
        self.lblOStatus_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 41, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_4.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_4.setObjectName("lblOStatus_4")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmOutput)
        self.frmInput_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmInput_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmInput_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmInput_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmInput_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 208))
        self.frmInput_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmInput_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmInput_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmInput_2.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmInput_2.setObjectName("frmInput_2")
        self.layoutWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_2)
        self.layoutWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 35, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_7.setObjectName("layoutWidget_7")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.setObjectName("lytV_Input_label_4")
        self.lblInput0_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput0_4.setObjectName("lblInput0_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput0_4)
        self.lblInput1_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput1_4.setObjectName("lblInput1_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput1_4)
        self.lblInput2_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput2_4.setObjectName("lblInput2_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput2_4)
        self.lblInput3_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
        self.lblInput3_4.setObjectName("lblInput3_4")
        self.lytV_Input_label_4.addWidget(self.lblInput3_4)
        self.layoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_2)
        self.layoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 46, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_8.setObjectName("layoutWidget_8")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.setObjectName("lytV_Input_Status_4")
        self.lblInput0_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput0_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput0_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput0_Status_4)
        self.lblInput1_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput1_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput1_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput1_Status_4)
        self.lblInput2_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput2_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput2_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput2_Status_4)
        self.lblInput3_Status_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_8)
        self.lblInput3_Status_4.setObjectName("lblInput3_Status_4")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_4.addWidget(self.lblInput3_Status_4)
        self.lblOStatus_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmInput_2)
        self.lblOStatus_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_5.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_5.setObjectName("lblOStatus_5")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmInput_2)
        self.frmInput_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(12)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frmInput_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frmInput_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frmInput_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 208))
        self.frmInput_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 208))
        self.frmInput_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(231, 226, 255);")
        self.frmInput_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frmInput_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frmInput_3.setLineWidth(1)
        self.frmInput_3.setObjectName("frmInput_3")
        self.layoutWidget_9 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_3)
        self.layoutWidget_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 35, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_9.setObjectName("layoutWidget_9")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.setObjectName("lytV_Input_label_5")
        self.lblInput0_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput0_5.setObjectName("lblInput0_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput0_5)
        self.lblInput1_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput1_5.setObjectName("lblInput1_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput1_5)
        self.lblInput2_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput2_5.setObjectName("lblInput2_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput2_5)
        self.lblInput3_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_9)
        self.lblInput3_5.setObjectName("lblInput3_5")
        self.lytV_Input_label_5.addWidget(self.lblInput3_5)
        self.layoutWidget_10 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.frmInput_3)
        self.layoutWidget_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 46, 178))
        self.layoutWidget_10.setObjectName("layoutWidget_10")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.setContentsMargins(7, 3, 4, 4)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.setSpacing(12)
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.setObjectName("lytV_Input_Status_5")
        self.lblInput0_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput0_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput0_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput0_Status_5)
        self.lblInput1_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput1_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput1_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput1_Status_5)
        self.lblInput2_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput2_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput2_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput2_Status_5)
        self.lblInput3_Status_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_10)
        self.lblInput3_Status_5.setObjectName("lblInput3_Status_5")
        self.lytV_Input_Status_5.addWidget(self.lblInput3_Status_5)
        self.lblOStatus_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frmInput_3)
        self.lblOStatus_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 30, 10))
        self.lblOStatus_6.setStyleSheet("Font:Bold;")
        self.lblOStatus_6.setObjectName("lblOStatus_6")
        self.lytH_Top.addWidget(self.frmInput_3)
        self.lytH_Top.setStretch(1, 10)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.lytH_Top)
        self.lytH_Chart = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lytH_Chart.setContentsMargins(1, -1, -1, -1)
        self.lytH_Chart.setSpacing(3)
        self.lytH_Chart.setObjectName("lytH_Chart")
        self.widget_Chart = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget_Chart.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget_Chart.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget_Chart.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.widget_Chart.setObjectName("widget_Chart")
        self.lytH_Chart.addWidget(self.widget_Chart)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.lytH_Chart)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.lblTitle.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">TEST DATA SHOW</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.lblInput0_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input0"))
        self.lblInput1_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input1"))
        self.lblInput2_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input2"))
        self.lblInput3_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input3"))
        self.lblInput0_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput1_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput2_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput3_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOStatus_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "INPUT"))
        self.lblOutput0_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOutput1_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOutput2_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOutput3_Status_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOutput0_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Output0"))
        self.lblOutput1_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Output1"))
        self.lblOutput2_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Output2"))
        self.lblOutput3_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Output3"))
        self.lblOStatus_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "INPUT"))
        self.lblOStatus_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>OUTPUT</p></body></html>"))
        self.lblInput0_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input0"))
        self.lblInput1_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input1"))
        self.lblInput2_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input2"))
        self.lblInput3_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input3"))
        self.lblInput0_Status_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput1_Status_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput2_Status_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput3_Status_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOStatus_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "INPUT"))
        self.lblInput0_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input0"))
        self.lblInput1_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input1"))
        self.lblInput2_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input2"))
        self.lblInput3_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Input3"))
        self.lblInput0_Status_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput1_Status_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput2_Status_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblInput3_Status_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0"))
        self.lblOStatus_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "INPUT"))

    def create_bar(self):
        # The QBarSet class represents a set of bars in the bar chart.
        # It groups several bars into a bar set

        set0 = QBarSet("Parwiz")
        set1 = QBarSet("Bob")
        set2 = QBarSet("Tom")
        set3 = QBarSet("Logan")
        set4 = QBarSet("Karim")

        set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6
        set1 << 5 << 0 << 0 << 4 << 0 << 7
        set2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 13 << 8 << 5
        set3 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 3 << 4 << 5
        set4 << 9 << 7 << 5 << 3 << 1 << 2

        series = QPercentBarSeries()
        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.append(set3)
        series.append(set4)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Percent Example")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        categories = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
        axis = QBarCategoryAxis()
        axis.append(categories)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setAxisX(axis, series)

        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.lytH_Chart.addWidget(chartView)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui.create_bar()
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```